# Weird SASS compiling behavior

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I moved my dev environment over to a different VPS and am having a weird timing issue when I save a SCSS file I'm working on. Attached below is a screen shot to give you an understanding of what I'm trying to explain.

Each block of output is another save, with nothing being changed at all in the SCSS file. You'll see that it often doesn't end on "overwrite style.css" and sometimes errors when *I know* there isn't actually an error. This means I have to keep hitting save in HOPES that it lands correctly on overwrite, or else it outputs a blank .css file. Waste of time, and frustrating..

It also seems to be doubling up sometimes on a single save..

Any ideas?

http://goo.gl/nQK0Q

Snippet below starts at line 972:

```
        li {
            -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
            padding: 1em 0;
            border: 1px solid #eff1f2;
            border-top: 1px solid $hr;
            &:hover {
                background: #e7ebec;
                border: 1px solid $hr;}
            .img-wrap {
                width: 12.188em;
                text-align: center;
                margin-right:1em;
                padding: 1em 0;}
            }
        .text-box {
            width: 26.688em;
            padding: 1.1em 0 0 0;
            h3 {
                font-size: 1.5em;
                text-transform: capitalize;}
            p {
                font-size: 0.75em;
                color: #aabcc8;
                font-weight: 600;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 0 0 .25em 0;
                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: $blue;}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the SASS/SCSS code that's throwing the error (on line 987, looks like the error is coming from `H3` tag's definition)?

Comment: Hey @ArmanH, I updated the question including the block with 987 in it. Thanks for taking a look but I think it erroneously says there is an error there due to a problematic compile.. or something.

Comment: I tried `sass-convert` to compile your SCSS into CSS without any problems. Probably not a SASS-specific issue. Are you watching/compiling on a remote machine, through SSH or VPS tunnel?

Comment: I am watching/compiling on a remote machine, via SSH.